# How to add buttons in a DataGridView from a List<> C#?

Tags: c#, list, button, datagridview, datasource

Like the title says, I would like to be able to add buttons in a DataGridView from a `List`.

What I have so far:

```
public class Users
{
    public Int64 UserID { get; set; }
    public DataGridViewButtonColumn EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public DataGridViewButtonColumn Gamertag { get; set; }
    public DataGridViewButtonColumn Xuid { get; set; }
    public String SignedIn { get; set; }
    public String AutoSignin { get; set; }
    public Image Gamerpic { get; set; }
}

private List<Users> GetUsersList()
{
    try
    {
        List<Users> list = new List<Users>();
        IEnumerable<XboxUser> users = _xbc.Users;
        foreach (XboxUser user in users)
        {
            DataGridViewButtonColumn EmailAddress = new DataGridViewButtonColumn()
            {
                Text = user.EmailAddress
            };
            DataGridViewButtonColumn Gamertag = new DataGridViewButtonColumn()
            {
                Text = user.GamerTag
            };
            DataGridViewButtonColumn Xuid = new DataGridViewButtonColumn()
            {
                Text = user.Xuid
            };
            Users xbuser = new Users()
            {
                UserID = user.UserId,
                EmailAddress = EmailAddress,
                Gamertag = Gamertag,
                Xuid = Xuid,
                SignedIn = user.IsSignedIn.ToString(),
                AutoSignin = user.AutoSignIn.ToString(),
                Gamerpic = GetImageFromUrl(Gamertag.Text)
            };
            list.Add(xbuser);
        }
        return list;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
    return null;
}

private void Bo_Refresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Users> listUsers = GetUsersList();
    Dg_UserList.DataSource = new BindingSource(new BindingList<Users>(listUsers), null);
}

private void Dg_UserList_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.ColumnIndex)
    {
        case 1:
            Clipboard.SetText(Dg_UserList.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["EmailAddress"].Value.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show("Email " + Dg_UserList.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["EmailAddress"].Value.ToString() + " has been copied in the clipboard.", "Copy to Clipboard", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            break;
        case 2:
            Clipboard.SetText(Dg_UserList.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Gamertag"].Value.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show("Gamertag " + Dg_UserList.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Gamertag"].Value.ToString() + " has been copied in the clipboard.", "Copy to Clipboard", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            break;
        case 3:
            Clipboard.SetText(Dg_UserList.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Xuid"].Value.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show("Xuid " + Dg_UserList.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Xuid"].Value.ToString() + " has been copied in the clipboard.", "Copy to Clipboard", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            break;
    }
}
```

Everything appears correctly (even the Image in Gamerpic) except the buttons, which show `DataGridViewButtonColumn { Name=, Index=-1 }` instead of a button with the right value on it.

I tried with `DataGridVewButtonCell` as well but does not work either.

However, when I click on a cell that is supposed to be a button, the `Clipboard.SetText` works but always put `DataGridViewButtonColumn { Name=, Index=-1 }` in it.

EDIT:
I have been able to do it with Strings instead... Looks less user friendly since there is no button to tell that you can click on it... but it works!  FOr sure I would prefer buttons instead :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Problem**

When DataSourced, the `DataGridView` will auto-create columns based on the data type for each column. By default, each column here is created as a `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn`, except for the column bound to an `Image` - which will default to a `DataGridViewImageColumn`. Even though you have three `DataGridViewButtonColumn` properties, they will be bound to text columns - which will set the value as follows (example):

```
NewRow.Cells[1].Value = DataSourceObject.EmailAddress.ToString();

// I.E. EmailAddress is a DataGridViewButtonColumn, so...
NewRow.Cells[1].Value = DataGridViewButtonColumn.ToString();

Console.WriteLine(DataGridViewButtonColumn.ToString()); // prints "DataGridViewButtonColumn { Name=, Index=-1 }"
```

**Solution**

Start with the `Users` class: Change all the `DatagridViewButtonColumn` properties to type `string`.

```
public class Users
{
    public Int64 UserID { get; set; }
    public String EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public String Gamertag { get; set; }
    public String Xuid { get; set; }
    public String SignedIn { get; set; }
    public String AutoSignin { get; set; }
    public Image Gamerpic { get; set; }
}
```

And change your `GetUserList` method to account for the differences:

```
private List<Users> GetUsersList()
{
    try
    {
        List<Users> list = new List<Users>();
        IEnumerable<XboxUser> users = _xbc.Users;

        foreach (XboxUser user in users)
        {
            Users xbuser = new Users()
            {
                UserID = user.UserId,
                EmailAddress = user.EmailAddress,
                Gamertag = user.Gamertag,
                Xuid = user.Xuid,
                SignedIn = user.IsSignedIn.ToString(),
                AutoSignin = user.AutoSignIn.ToString(),
                Gamerpic = GetImageFromUrl(Gamertag.Text)
            };

            list.Add(xbuser);
        }

        return list;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }

    return null;
}
```

And finally, in your Form constructor or Load event - before you've bound your data - manually add the columns like so:

```
Dg_UserList.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

DataGridViewTextBoxColumn userCol = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
DataGridViewButtonColumn emailCol = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
DataGridViewButtonColumn tagCol = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
DataGridViewButtonColumn xuidCol = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn signCol = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn autoCol = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
DataGridViewImageColumn picCol = new DataGridViewImageColumn();

userCol.Name = "UserID";                    // Allows access to columns or
emailCol.Name = "EmailAddress";             // cells in the following manner:
tagCol.Name = "Gamertag";                   // dgv.Rows[index].Cells["Name"];
xuidCol.Name = "Xuid";
signCol.Name = "SignedIn";
autoCol.Name = "AutoSignin";
picCol.Name = "Gamerpic";

userCol.DataPropertyName = "UserID";        // MUST match DataSource properties.
emailCol.DataPropertyName = "EmailAddress"; // Allows DataSourced columns to match
tagCol.DataPropertyName = "Gamertag";       // up with manually created columns.
xuidCol.DataPropertyName = "Xuid";
signCol.DataPropertyName = "SignedIn";
autoCol.DataPropertyName = "AutoSignin";
picCol.DataPropertyName = "Gamerpic";

userCol.HeaderText = "User ID";             // Allows displaying different text
emailCol.HeaderText = "Email Address";      // for the column headers.
tagCol.HeaderText = "Gamer Tag";
xuidCol.HeaderText = "Xuid";
signCol.HeaderText = "Signed In";
autoCol.HeaderText = "Auto Sign in";
picCol.HeaderText = "Avatar";

Dg_UserList.Columns.Add(userCol);
Dg_UserList.Columns.Add(emailCol);
Dg_UserList.Columns.Add(tagCol);
Dg_UserList.Columns.Add(xuidCol);
Dg_UserList.Columns.Add(signCol);
Dg_UserList.Columns.Add(autoCol);
Dg_UserList.Columns.Add(picCol);
```

This will allow you to create your button columns but will still allow you to bind the data instead of manually adding each row. Thanks to `DataPropertyName` the button cells will correctly display the bound cell value.

Comment: Wow Thanks a lot @OhBeWise It really works! And now I understand more how the DataGridView works.

Comment: @SteveRousseau "*And now I understand more how the DataGridView works.*" Mission accomplished. Glad to help! :)